# MooTools issue on IE and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, mootools

It looks mootools-1.2.5 have an issue on IE 8  and chrome when you use:

```
$(document).addEvent('domready',function(){alert("test");});
```

but their home page says: "MooTools is compatible and fully tested with Safari, Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome."

Comment: How are you referencing the library? I was able to run this code on IE8 and Chrome with no problems and got the alert on both browsers. Please show how you're adding MooTools to the page.

Comment: I am adding it the same way like other .js files   `<script type="text/javascript"
src="/scripts/lib/mootools-1.2.5.js"></script>`

Comment: According to the official mooTools documentation states the use of window NOT $(document) for domready "This event is only available to the window Element." Source: http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Utilities/DomReady

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add the domready event to window, not document. that's all. reading the manual helps - even the tag wiki here has this very example:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mootools/info